# Amazon EC2 and Prestashop

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, prestashop, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are facing serious problem with Amazon EC2 and Prestashop.

We deployed Prestashop with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and we setup S3 for media servers. When we are uploading products with Images in bulk with csv import feature, we are facing the below problems.

1. New EC2 instance is getting created and loosing all the css and js files (cache) and the media servers in the database are getting emptied. Due to this again we need to generate all the css and js files and upload to S3 server every time, because the previously generate css and js are now useless.
2. While downloading the images, if the new EC2 instance is created, loosing the images too.

Kindly help us for better solution for the above problems.

Best Regards,

Comment: Do you have the zero downtime option activated in EB?

Answer (score 0):

Try using U[sing Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon Elastic File System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html) -
upload the images, css and js files onto the File system and mount into the EC2 instances that would be created by Elastic Beanstalk

> With Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS), you can create network >file systems that can be mounted by instances across multiple >Availability Zones. An Amazon EFS file system is an AWS resource that >uses security groups to control access over the network that's in your >default or custom VPC.

> In an Elastic Beanstalk environment, you can use Amazon EFS to create a >shared directory that stores files for your application that users >upload and modify. Your application can treat a mounted Amazon EFS >volume such as local storage. That way, you don't have to change your >application code to scale up to multiple instances.

You would need to create a configuration file to tell Elastic Beanstalk to mount the file system on each instance. created

> Elastic Beanstalk provides configuration files that you can use to >create and mount Amazon EFS file systems. You can create an Amazon EFS >volume as part of your environment or mount an Amazon EFS volume that >you created independently of Elastic Beanstalk.

Hope it helps